# Z-scoring (or alternatives) while not creating artifacts

Tags: scikit-learn, z-score

So I'm running into an issue I can illustrate as follows. Lets say you have a shipment of fruit, of various kinds. You want to compare across shipments. You, for some reason, decide to Z-score these shipments. In the first shipment, you have 10 tons of Apples and 10 tons of Oranges. In the second shipment, you have 10 tons of Apples and 20 tons of Oranges. If you Z Score within shipments, It seems like you'll run into an issue, that the score for Apples will end up negative, as it is now below the mean, whereas it is 0 in the original case, Despite the fact the only change was amount of Oranges, you'll get the false impression Apples went down.

Does this problem have a formal name? What are the approaches to preserve these kinds of changes? Are there alternatives to Z scoring?